# Upgrade Sitecore 8.2 XP Database to Sitecore 10.2 XM Database

Tags: upgrade

This question is related to the upgrade approach of the Sitecore Database. There are plenty of documents available on Sitecore and other blog posts and articles about How to upgrade the Sitecore database, but this is different.

I have an application in `Sitecore 8.2 XP` and it needs to be migrated on `Sitecore 10.2 XM`, **please focus on instance XM instead of XP**.

`Sitecore 8.2 XP` instance launchpad as below:
[image]

`Sitecore 10.2 XM` instance launchpad as below:
[image]

I have upgraded the Database using the SQL scripts provided by Sitecore [here](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/93CC3A931DB7459AAC38BA111E0DD16D.ashx?date=20211207T101247) and now my `Sitecore 10.2 XM` instance launchpad as below:
[image]

Can anyone please guide how can I get rid of these icons and options under the `Marketing Application` section?

**Note:**

1. I have not published code yet on the `Sitecore 10.2 XM` instance, I have attached only the upgraded Database. So there are no config and other changes.
2. I have also run the [Sitecore UpdateApp Tool](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore%20UpdateApp%20Tool/1x/Sitecore%20UpdateApp%20Tool%20120), after upgrading the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the `Marketing Applications` buttons on the Sitecore launchpad, we can switch to the core database through the Sitecore desktop, then go to the item path

> /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Marketing

From here, we can delete the entire Marketing subtree. After doing this, the instance will automatically restore a child item `Forms`, which is expected because XM still allows users to use this feature. To understand more about this, Sitecore recommends this article:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-xp-feature-compatibility-in-xm-scaled-packages.html.

Unfortunately, Sitecore does not have any simple steps to recommend to completely get rid of all analytics and marketing items from our databases. The above-suggested step only helps to hide the buttons, which should be enough to prevent our instance from running into any error related to Marketing and Analytics.

**Some other ways we can try:**

1. If we did not add any custom item to your core database, then we can simply consider discarding the old core database and using the new core database which came with your fresh XM installation.
2. If we have custom items in the core database, we can try to add them into an item package using package designer (accessible from the desktop), which allows for creating item packages from core database items. Then, install the item package on your new XM core DB.

I have used the [Sitecore Razl: Tool for Compare and Merge](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl) the database and find out the customization into the core DB.

For more details about the Sitecore Razl refer to the documentation: https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/razl/comparing.html

**Note:** I raised the support ticket to Sitecore and there is no documented and tested upgrade path from XP to XM, unfortunately, Sitecore doesn't have such SQL scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding a patch file to disable xDB.

Change the Xdb.Enabled and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled settings to false.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html

Please see example patch file to switch off xDB here:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
        <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
        <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT 21/09/22**

Apologies but I didnt have time to respond previously. I can see you have accepted answer, so may not need this anymore. But here it is anyway!

In your question, you ask how to remove those buttons from the dashboard. Please see screenshots below, which show an XP installation before and after the patch file I suggested above be applied.

[image: Before Patch]

As you can see with the screen shot below, applying the patch removes exactly the buttons that you mention in your question.

[image: After Patch applied]

Comment: Thanks, @Dean OBrien, but the Sitecore XM instance does not have XDB and Marketing.xDB folder under the App_Config folder.

Comment: If you go to /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and search for "xDB.enabled" does it show true?

Comment: xDB.enabled does not exist in showconfig.aspx. It's Sitecore XM, not XP.

Comment: Thanks himmat, i appreciate that it shouldn't be there, but said you have upgraded from XP. Also the features you have identified all belong to XP. I have updated answer with link to path file example. Please try creating folder app_config/include/z.custom/ and add that patch file with values set to false

Comment: I have not published any code yet. I have updated the question with a note. By adding the patch file it is showing in showconfig.aspx that xDB.enabled is false. But I am not getting to understand what is the relation between this setting and Sitecore desktop interface icons.

Comment: In sitecore XP, switching off xDB using that patch/setting among other things, removes the marketing icons from the dashboard (as they are not relevant with out xDB data)

Comment: Tried, but with no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138586/discussion-between-himmat-singh-dulawat-and-dean-obrien).

Comment: Thanks for the response and update. But you can see that after that still you have Campaign Creator and Marketing Control Panel options. I have accepted the other answer because it serves the exact purpose and am  voting for your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to clean up the content databases:** Because all the default items have been moved into resource files, you must remove them from your databases.
Database clean-up is a one-time operation.

The `Sitecore.UpdateApp` tool removes these items, if they have not been modified, from the Core, Master, and Web databases. If you have modified these items, they are not removed and the tool adds a list of them to its log file.

**To clean up the content databases:**

1. On the Sitecore Launchpad, open the Control Panel, in the Database section, click Clean up databases, select all the databases, and then click Clean.
2. Locate the [Sitecore.UpdateApp 1.2.0](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_UpdateApp_Tool/1x/Sitecore_UpdateApp_Tool_120.aspx) for *Sitecore X.X.X rev XXXXXX.zip* file and extract its contents to a folder, for example, C:\Sitecore.UpdateApp
3. Copy the license file to the Data folder of the tool, for example, C:\Sitecore.UpdateApp\Data\license.xml.
4. In the `C:\Sitecore.UpdateApp\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config` file, update the connections to your databases. If you do not have a security database, use the connection to the core database.
5. Open a Command Prompt in the tool folder and run:

```
Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe clean
```

The number of items that are removed from each database is listed in the Command Prompt window.

[image]

6. To clear the caches, open the `<instance_url>\sitecore\admin\cache.aspx` page, click Refresh and then click Clear.

All the above steps are mentioned in [this](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/93CC3A931DB7459AAC38BA111E0DD16D.ashx?date=20211207T101247) guide: (Step 3.1.3)

Comment: Thanks, @Raman, as mentioned I already upgraded the DB, and the above-mentioned steps I have performed. Its also mentioned in the PDF document which I linked in my question.