# Downgrading from XP to XM

Tags: license

Has anyone ever done an XP to XM downgrade, what was involved?

Does anyone know what constitutes an XP feature? Is it based on features, assemblies we include, or something else?

Is there a page / list we can query to let us know which features are in use? Docs are not very helpful around this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to downgrade from `XP` to `XM` then the below link will give you all the information on the features that you will miss in XM.

https://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-xm-vs-xp

https://bala.one/is-sitecore-xp-to-xm-a-downgrade/

And for your question about "**what constitutes an XP feature**?" the answer is if you download both packages, you will see the lesser `DLLs` and `configs` in the Sitecore XM package, which will reduce features in that.

The above links will also give you the licensing information between both of them.

For your last question, the feature you will find in the above links as well. And you can see that on Sitecore documents.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-xp-feature-compatibility-in-xm-scaled-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 9.1 and later, the XM Scaled packages do not include the binaries and configuration files used by Sitecore XP. Therefore, only a limited set of Sitecore XP features are supported.

**Fully compatible**
The following features can run Experience Manager without any changes:

- Content editing in the Experience Editor and Content Editor

**Compatible with limited functionality**
The following features can run Experience Manager with limitations:

- Personalization - only in-session personalization is available.
- Device detection – The device database exists on the instance and it is possible to use the API for custom development. The personalization rules based on the device are not available.
- IP Geolocation detection – The IP Geolocation service can be enabled using the API, but personalization rules are not available.
- Sitecore Forms - performance tracking, robot detection and submit action (that all rely on the Marketing Automation component) are not available.

**Incompatible**
The following features are incompatible with Experience Manager if it has been installed using XM packages:

- Experience Explorer
- Campaign Creator
- Commerce Connect
- Content testing
- Email Experience Manager
- Experience Analytics
- Experience Profile
- List Manager
- Path Analyzer
- Segmentation
- Federated Experience Manager
- Marketing Automation

Comment: > IP Geolocation detection - actually that's not true, personalisation rules are available for this one. However it does work slightly differently on the back end how it caches the IP.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I'll have to go with Sumit on this one though :thumb

Comment: Thanks. This is one more question with an answer that can help you if you are planning for it. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32599/upgrade-sitecore-8-2-xp-database-to-sitecore-10-2-xm-database